# Document class scrartcl - printing bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, koma-script

I can't get the bibliography to print when I use document class scrartcl. Can anyone help me understand why?

```
\documentclass[epsfig]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{epsfig,amsmath,graphicx}
\usepackage{float,listings,verbatim,booktabs,stmaryrd}
\usepackage{rotating,multirow,longtable}
\usepackage{subfig,wrapfig,caption,hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{ref}
\end{document}
```

ref.bib file contents:

```
@ARTICLE{Mooney2014,
    AUTHOR  = "Michael A. Mooney and Joel T. Nigg and Shannon K. McWeeney and Beth Wilmot",
    TITLE   = "Functional and genomic context in pathway analysis of GWAS data",
    YEAR    = "2014",
    JOURNAL = "Trends in Genetics",
    VOLUME  = "30",
    NUMBER  = "9",
    PAGES   = 390--400
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed in your bib entry two `"`:

```
PAGES   = "390--400"
```

Adding them your MWE compiles.  BTW: better use `{...}` instead of `"..."`.
But now you get only an empty bibliography because you did not cite any bib entry in your MWE.

Please see the following MWE. It comiles and because I added command `\nocite{*}` (to test all bib entries!) it shows an bibliography after compiling three times (pdflatex, bibtex, pdflatex, pdflatex).

MWE (package `filecontents`is used to have bib file and tex code in one MWE, only for this example!):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{Mooney2014,
  AUTHOR  = {Michael A. Mooney and Joel T. Nigg and Shannon K. McWeeney and Beth Wilmot},
  TITLE   = {Functional and genomic context in pathway analysis of GWAS data},
  YEAR    = {2014},
  JOURNAL = {Trends in Genetics},
  VOLUME  = {30},
  NUMBER  = {9},
  PAGES   = {390--400},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[%
%  epsfig % not needed for this problem!
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
%\usepackage{epsfig,amsmath,graphicx}
%\usepackage{float,listings,verbatim,booktabs,stmaryrd}
%\usepackage{rotating,multirow,longtable}
%\usepackage{subfig,wrapfig,caption}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image]

Comment: BRILLIANT! I forgot that unreferenced references are not printed - silly me! Also thanks for the tip about "" versus {}. Very thankful!

Answer (score 1):

In your MWE, the key `Mooney2014` is not cited. Unused keys are not added to the list of references by default. A simple way to change this behaviour is `\nocite{Mooney2014}` or, of course, `\cite{Mooney2014}` (`\nocite{*}` for all unused keys).